# Why does this regular expression match odd files?

Tags: grep

Just playing with regular expressions to learn.  Why does it match the other files: errsort, pytest.py, etc.?  On the second line adding a question mark on the end matched two more files.  Tried grep basic expressions too.

Thanks!

```
$ ls -x | egrep -i "(aa)(dd)?(cc)?(dd)?((bb(ccdd)?(bb)?)?)|(ccdd)"
aa       aaaa       aabb     aabbaa     aabbbb    aabbccdd  aabbccddcc  
aabbddbb
aaccaa   aaccdd   aaddaa   aaddccddccdd  aaddee  errsort   pytest.py   TEST
$ ls -x | egrep -i "(aa)(dd)?(cc)?(dd)?((bb(ccdd)?(bb)?)?)|(ccdd)?"
aa       aaaa     aabb    aabbaa        aabbbb  aabbccdd  aabbccddcc  aabbddbb
aaccaa   aaccdd   aaddaa  aaddccddccdd  aaddee  errsort   pytest.py   TEST
test.sh  vimtest

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 3.7
```

```
$ ls | egrep -i "(aa)(dd)?(cc)?(dd)?((bb(ccdd)?(bb)?)?)|(ccdd)"
aa
aaaa
aabb
aabbaa
aabbbb
aabbccdd
aabbccddcc
aabbddbb
aaccaa
aaccdd
aaddaa
aaddccddccdd
aaddee
$ ls -x | egrep -i "(aa)(dd)?(cc)?(dd)?((bb(ccdd)?(bb)?)?)|(ccdd)?"
aa   aaaa     aabb    aabbaa    aabbbb  aabbccdd  aabbccddcc  aabbddbb
aaccaa   aaccdd   aaddaa  aaddccddccdd  aaddee  errsort   pytest.py   TEST
test.sh  vimtest
$ ls | egrep -i "(aa)(dd)?(cc)?(dd)?((bb(ccdd)?(bb)?)?)|(ccdd)?"
aa
aaaa
aabb
aabbaa
aabbbb
aabbccdd
aabbccddcc
aabbddbb
aaccaa
aaccdd
aaddaa
aaddccddccdd
aaddee
errsort
pytest.py
TEST
test.sh
vimtest
$
```

```
$ ls | egrep -io "(aa)(dd)?(cc)?(dd)?((bb(ccdd)?(bb)?)?)|(ccdd)?"
aa
aa
aa
aabb
aabb
aa
aabbbb
aabbccdd
aabbccdd
aabb
aacc
aa
aaccdd
aadd
aa
aaddccdd
ccdd
aadd
```

This doesn't give you the color, but the bold is red on my screen to indicate the pattern match i think.
The files on the bottom don't have any red.
Removing -x did affect output on the first one.
The -o helps a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An optional match like `(ccdd)?` is exactly that: optional.

It could happen that the matched text is **empty**, but still, that is a match, a line that has a match.

```
$ ls -x
aa   aaaa       aabb  aabbaa   aabbbb   aabbccdd  aabbccddcc  aabbddbb  aaccaa  aaccdd  aaddaa  aaddccddccdd  aaddee
errsort  pytest.py  TEST  test.sh  vimtest

$ ls -x | cat
aa   aaaa     aabb    aabbaa    aabbbb  aabbccdd  aabbccddcc  aabbddbb
aaccaa   aaccdd   aaddaa  aaddccddccdd  aaddee  errsort   pytest.py   TEST
test.sh  vimtest
```

It is important to understand that when the `ls` output is piped, it changes.
Now there are three lines to match with the grep.

As the first and second lines match on the (several) `aa`, both are printed.

```
$ ls -x | egrep -i "(aa)(dd)?(cc)?(dd)?((bb(ccdd)?(bb)?)?)|(ccdd)"
aa   aaaa     aabb    aabbaa    aabbbb  aabbccdd  aabbccddcc  aabbddbb
aaccaa   aaccdd   aaddaa  aaddccddccdd  aaddee  errsort   pytest.py   TEST

$ ls -x | egrep -i "(aa)(dd)?(cc)?(dd)?((bb(ccdd)?(bb)?)?)|(ccdd)?"
aa   aaaa     aabb    aabbaa    aabbbb  aabbccdd  aabbccddcc  aabbddbb
aaccaa   aaccdd   aaddaa  aaddccddccdd  aaddee  errsort   pytest.py   TEST
test.sh  vimtest
```

As shown, the third line gets a match on the empty string due to the `(ccdd)?`.

I am assuming the format of your list of files is incorrect.

Comment: It was matching those even with LS input from file (one file per line (ls > inputFile)).  It is because of the hanging |(ccdd)? catching all matches.  I thought the starting aa would stop that.  When I grouped the last |(ccdd) into parentheses with the previous group all output was as expected.

Comment: You are using `...|(ccdd)?` which means "something" or the optional `(ccdd)`, which does match "anything", yes, To have the aa avoid that you need something similar to `aa(...|(ccdd)?)`. @kserwick

Answer (score 1):

`grep` isn't **matching** the files like `errsort` .... it's matching the line, and the only thing it actually matches is the `(aa)` (everything else is optional because of the `?`). Because you chose `ls -x` the output of ls is *one long line* and the `aa` matches.

Why the non-matching alternativ group shows more files I can't understand, maybe a bug in egrep.